# jumbotron text on left image on right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Jumbotron with 2 divs, one to display text and one for an image.  It works fine on very small and large screen but image overflows badly on medium to small. I would like the image to either shrink to suit or else vanish completely.

I have not made any changes to any `@media`.

Here is the code I have:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-6 col-sm-12" >
            <h1>Dive Gweedore </h1>
            <p>A place of wonder and crystal clear water</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">
     Durability</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " role="button">
     Strength</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">
     Brilliance</a>
  </p>
        </div> 
        <div class=" col-md-6">
        <img class="showcase-image" src="http://localhost/shop/image/cache/catalog/hand.png">
        </div>          
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert Bootstrap img-responsive class in your image.

```css
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```